# Open JDK error when I Install Android Studio Arctic Fox on Xubuntu?

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, java, openjdk, android-studio

I am trying to install Android Studio Arctic Fox on my Xubuntu 20.04 using the official guide from here : https://developer.android.com/studio/install#64bit-libs

I downloaded the .zip file and unzip it into the /opt/ directory but the problem is when I go to the bin folder of android-stuido and open the terminal and run the commnad ./studio.sh to install Android Studio I get this error in the terminal:

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Multiple garbage collectors selected

I got to say that I used to have Android Studio version 4.1.3 and I removed it including every folder related to it before installing the newer version. also my OpenJDK version is 11.0.11

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Just type this command and hit enter.

If you want to install jdk 8, then type

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

If you want to install only jre, then

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

After that, register the jdk path with JAVA_HOME variable in windows. For linux, you can do it in multiple ways which can be easily learned from internet.

Then open Android studio and see of it's solved.

Comment: Do you have Android Studio Arctic Fox version installed on your device?? actually it needs OpenJdk 11 to run

Comment: I am using windows. But I installed studio on Pop Os directly from its app store..so it was running without any problem.